# why admob stopped working after pushing an app update?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, admob, firebase-admob

My partner deployed an android game and integrated admob, all was working fine, but after pushing a new app update it stopped showing ads, also no error is displayed on her admob account.

any idea what it might be the error code is 3, however all other apps are showing ads at her location.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 3 means that AdMob does not have any ad to give you. It might be for a few reasons:

- You just created new ad units, time for admob to correctly set them up
- You are requesting too high CPMs, no filling
- You're have is being reviewed and they didn't warn you (however it should be, but it might happen)
- You don't have enough daily requests so you will be filled with poor ads
- Might be a problem on their side
- You modified your ad algorithm, for instance, asking too many ads without showing them, so you won't be prioritised.

Anyway, you should wait a week and contact the support (which is pretty slow in those times)